# Google Sheets Security

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've been working on perfecting a couple of my google sheets for work. I need to share it with my coworkers, but I want to find a way to protect my hard work from being copied and repurposed by others.

They need to have edit access, so that eliminates "Disable options to down, print, and copy for commenters and viewers".'

I need to make sure this document doesn't get duplicated a dozen times by everyone the moment I provide them all with edit access. Any advice?

Comment: How do you want to prevent somebody who has edit access from copying ? Even if it were possible to prevent the document from being duplicated, people could still manually copy-paste contents from your spreadsheet to their spreadsheet. What you can do is to copy only the contents to which the users need access into a separate spreadsheet, provide the users with access to that spreadsheet only and set-up a synchronization that will incorporate the edits made by the users into the main spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

For any of those coming back to this feed, I've created a google script that if someone tries to make a copy of my document, the moment they open their doc, the entire sheet gets wiped (what I like to call 'self destruct').

So it is possible, despite the entire internet and google themselves saying it's not.